# Law of Total Variance

Tags: probability, statistics

The problem along with the solution is below. All steps are clear to me, I am just unable to figure out how the $var(X|Y)=nY(1-Y)$ was obtained. Some clarification would be appreciated.

We consider $n$ independent tosses of a biased coin whose probability of heads, $Y$, is uniformly distributed over the interval $[0,1]$.

With $X$ being the number of heads obtained, we have $E[X|Y]=nY$ and $var(X|Y)=nY(1-Y)$. Thus,

$$E[var(X|Y)] = E[ny(1-Y)]=.....= \frac{n}{6}$$
Furthermore,
$$var(E(X|Y)=\frac{n^2}{12}$$
Therefore, by the law of total variance, we have the sum of the two parts above
$$\frac{n}{6}+\frac{n^2}{12}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It follows immediately from the distribution of $X|Y$. You have to notice that it follows a binomial distribution $\operatorname{Bin}(n, Y)$, since there are $n$ independent trials, with probability $Y$ of success, and $X$ counts the number of heads (success). Therefore $E[X|Y] = nY$ and $\operatorname{Var}(X|Y) = nY(1-Y)$.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I am having a difficulty fully understanding all that is going on in this question. For instance when you say "the distribution of $X|Y$." This is not fully clear to me as I thought our random variable is $E(X|Y)$ not just $X|Y$? Also I am having a difficulty understanding the different distributions that are taking place. For instance I understand that $Y$ is uniform, $E(X|Y)$ or X|Y as you said is I guess binomial? And I don't know what type $X$ is, or is that not relevant?

Comment: I don't know much theory, but as I recall $X|Y\sim \operatorname{Bin}(n, Y)$, which might be an abuse of notation. I'm taking an educated guess here, but it seems like the distribution of $E[X|Y]$ is a scaled uniform, $(0, n)$, since $E[X|Y] = nY$. You don't need to know the unconditional distribution of $X$, but you can calculate it using the usual methods.